# How to set batch size when inference with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, updatebatchsize

If batch size = 1, it's easy to write code, but the average time for one image is longer than the case of batch size is 30, 40 or others.

Comment: Could you provide more details?  It is not quite clear what you’re asking.  Do you have a code sample etc?

Comment: For example, I have 10000 images of mnist to test, if I set batch_size=100, meaning that the input of the network is (100,28,28,1), it takes only 2.9s totally in 1080 Ti. If I set batch_size=1, meaning that the input of the network is (1,28,28,1), it takes 17.8s. But if I use it to detect in real-time, the batch_size is just 1. So I want to know if there is some methods to make it faster when batch_size is 1. Thanks !

Comment: Ya, I think you’re stuck. You’ll get much higher throughout using larger batch but incur latency.  You could try quantitize your network to make single invocations faster.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand well what you said. I just want to know if is can be as fast as batch_size=100 when batch_size=1. Thanks !

Comment: The answer is: no. BTW, batch sizes are usually a power of two.